# Attempting to Reconnect Access Front End to Back End DB results in VBA Error: "Compile Error: Can't find Project or Library"

Tags: database, vba, ms-access

A client gave me a front end of a MS Access database to do some work on. I am now attempting to reconnect it to the back-end on her computer. When I open it (the front end) on her computer, I get the error:[image]

When I click "ok" the VBA code editor opens up and I get "Compile Error: Cant find Project or Library". Here is a screenshot:
[image]

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: From the VB Editor's main menu, choose Tools->References.  One or more of your project's references are marked "MISSING".  Which?

Comment: I am unable to select the references tab. It's not highlighted etc.

Comment: Is the project still in "break mode"?  If so, click the Reset icon (blue square) or choose Run->Reset from the menu.  Then try Tools->References again.

Comment: Ok. Now I can select References. The reference missing is "Microsoft Excel 15.0 Object Library"

Comment: You developed with a version of Office newer than your clients, so Access upgraded the Excel reference to your version.  Select the Excel object library version which is available on the client's machine.  Longer term, convert your code which uses Excel to late binding --- that way you don't need no Excel reference at all.

Comment: I understand. However, When I open up the front end now, all I get is an infinite progress wheel and a message in the bottom left of the window which says 'ready.' Do you know what I should do from here to reconnect to the back end?

Comment: I got it to work. Turns out  the "Microsoft Office 14.0 Access Database engine object library" was conflicting with the "Excel" Library. I unchecked the former, and now it works fine. TY for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As HansUp has identified, it seems that you've done development in Access 2013 and then given the database to a user that is using Access 2010 or possibly 2007.

Access (and most Office applications0 have a #Feature# that automatically upgrades the references to the host application library (in your case Access) and the Office library.

If you, or a colleague are trying to open an Access Database that has been opened on a newer version of Access, then, when opening on an older version of Access, you'll need to explicitly select the correct references for Access and Office.

For example, if you opened the database in Access 2013, then you'll probably have references in positions 1 and 3:

```
Microsoft Access 15.0 Object Library
Microsoft Office 15.0 Object Library
```

If you want to open that database in Access 2010, you'll need to ensure that these references are in positions 1 and 3:

```
Microsoft Access 14.0 Object Library
Microsoft Office 14.0 Object Library
```

If you want to open that database in Access 2007, you'll need to ensure that these references are in positions 1 and 3:

```
Microsoft Access 12.0 Object Library
Microsoft Office 12.0 Object Library
```

Just remember that merely opening a database in Access is usally enough for Access to make the adjustments to the references for you, *when you're opening a in a newer version*, and those changes are automatically saved in the database.

As a rule of thumb, try to develop in the same version of Access as your users, and try to ensure that all users of a database are using the same version of Access.

If your team is migrating to a newer version, in stages, decide in advance when various databases are upgraded, and assign responsibility for various databases to users with common Access versions.